# Функция, возвращающая текст для exit status codes, defined in sysexits.h?

Tags: c, linux

Кто-нибудь знает функцию, подобную [strerror](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror) или [strsignal](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strsignal) только для exit status кодов?

Или, может, какой-то исходник для `sh/perl/python/...` с сообщениями "общего пользования" (согласен, дурацкая формулировка) откуда можно скопипастить.

Сами коды и  тексты в виде комментариев есть в файле [/usr/include/sysexits.h](http://linux.die.net/include/sysexits.h),  ничего лучшего [strexit](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/sendmail/sendmail-32/sendmail/libsm/strexit.c) и [sysexits](http://opensource.apple.com/source/sendmail/sendmail-26.2/sendmail/sendmail/sysexits.c) из Sendmail (естественно, с почтовой спецификой) я что-то найти не могу.

**Update**
Решил взять такие сообщения

```
const char *SysExitMsg[] =
{
        /* 64 USAGE */          "command line usage error",
        /* 65 DATAERR */        "data format error",
        /* 66 NOINPUT */        "cannot open input",
        /* 67 NOUSER */         "addressee unknown",
        /* 68 NOHOST */         "host name unknown",
        /* 69 UNAVAILABLE */    "service unavailable",
        /* 70 SOFTWARE */       "internal software error",
        /* 71 OSERR */          "system error (e.g., can't fork)",
        /* 72 OSFILE */         "critical OS file missing",
        /* 73 CANTCREAT */      "can't create (user) output file",
        /* 74 IOERR */          "input/output error",
        /* 75 TEMPFAIL */       "temp failure; user is invited to retry",
        /* 76 PROTOCOL */       "remote error in protocol",
        /* 77 NOPERM */         "permission denied",
        /* 78 CONFIG */         "configuration error",
        0
};
```

Комментарии приветсвуются.

Кстати, сразу вопрос в тему, **с каким кодом лучше выходить по out of memory?**

(мне кажется, что OSERR).

**Update 2**

Хочу уточнить вопрос. На самом деле более всего мне интересен именно *текст сообщений*.

Вот еще один вариант из Sendmail [sysexits.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/sendmail/sendmail-26.2/sendmail/sendmail/sysexits.c)

```
char *SysExMsg[] =
{
        /* 64 USAGE */          " 500 5.0.0 Bad usage",
        /* 65 DATAERR */        " 501 5.6.0 Data format error",
        /* 66 NOINPUT */        ":550 5.3.0 Cannot open input",
        /* 67 NOUSER */         " 550 5.1.1 User unknown",
        /* 68 NOHOST */         " 550 5.1.2 Host unknown",
        /* 69 UNAVAILABLE */    " 554 5.0.0 Service unavailable",
        /* 70 SOFTWARE */       ":554 5.3.0 Internal error",
        /* 71 OSERR */          ":451 4.0.0 Operating system error",
        /* 72 OSFILE */         ":554 5.3.5 System file missing",
        /* 73 CANTCREAT */      ":550 5.0.0 Can't create output",
        /* 74 IOERR */          ":451 4.0.0 I/O error",
        /* 75 TEMPFAIL */       " 450 4.0.0 Deferred",
        /* 76 PROTOCOL */       " 554 5.5.0 Remote protocol error",
        /* 77 NOPERM */         ":550 5.0.0 Insufficient permission",
        /* 78 CONFIG */         " 554 5.3.5 Local configuration error"
};
```

Comment: Хотя, в [sysexits.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/sendmail/sendmail-26.2/sendmail/sendmail/sysexits.c) похоже все же есть подходящая структура...

Comment: все эти коды - программнозависимы. То есть, разработчики каждой программы выбирают их на свое усмотрение. 

Узнать расшифровки обычно можно в исходниках и манах (секция DIAGNOSTICS или RETURN VALUES).

Comment: @KoVadim, я понимаю, что многие программисты не придерживаются соглашений о кодах из sysexits.h, но все же надеялся, что у кого-нибудь есть список сообщений, отличающийся от комментариев в этом файле (текст, что я привел -- это они).

Comment: ну не все ошибки можно привести к "стандартным".

Comment: @KoVadim, я почему-то считал, что это очевидно. И нигде не говорил, что собираюсь приводить все коды возврата и сообщения к стандартным (или призывать всех к этому).

--

Попробую спросить немного попроще -- если программа вернула код из sysexits.h, то какое сообщение записать в лог?

Comment: если программа абстрактная, то возвращайте число, главное его обрамить правильно (типа "Error code: XXXX"), чтобы потом было легко искать по логу. А потом числа можно и декодировать по листику:)

плюсы

 - числа занимают меньше места
 - их легче обрабатывать
 - исключается возможность, что на два разных числа будет один текст.

Comment: Добавил **Update 2**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API для статуса завершения программ  ([`exit(status)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exit.html), `return 0` в `main()`, итд) не предполагает наличия какого-либо текста.

За исключением значений [`return 0`, `exit(EXIT_STATUS)`, `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exit.html) общепринятых стандартов не существует. Каждая программа может свою схему придумывать что оставшиеся коды означают и печатается ли что-либо перед завершением с определённым кодом. В POSIX только 8-бит интерпретируются как код завершения ([`WEXITSTATUS(status)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html)). На Windows [`GetExitCodeProcess()` возвращает целых 32-бита](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27870379/4279).

Это позволяет некоторым программам использовать десятки кодов возврата. Объяснения что каждый код означает можно найти в их документации, например, [если `curl` возвращает `47`, то это означает](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html):

> Too many redirects. When following redirects, curl hit the maximum amount.

Другой пример [`bash`, где `128 + N` статус](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/dict/terms/exit_status#values) означает, что команда завершилась с сигналом `N` (точный список сигналов зависит от системы, [например, на linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)).

Программа может использовать один и тот же статус для разных ошибок, например, `grep` возвращает `2` на любую ошибку (такую как неверная опция командной строки или несуществующий входной файл) на моей системе. `grep` возвращает `0` в случае успеха (что-то найдено) и `1`, если не найдено (как правило). Многие другие поисковые команды, следуют этой схеме.

Другая полезная схема: использовать статус `2` для неверного использования программы (несуществующие опции, их несовместимое сочетание, значения опций вне допустимых диапазонов, итд) и `1` для остальных ошибок. `2` указывает на ошибку автора скрипта (баг), а `1` на возможно временную ошибку в окружении (например, нет интернета, файла).

Подавляющее большинство программ используют только два статуса: успех и провал. Существуют рекомендации по формату сообщений об ошибках, [например, в GNU](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Errors).

Основные задачи сообщений об ошибках—это указать пути решения возникшей проблемы пользователю (что может быть очень специфично для конкретного приложения) или помочь найти причину бага в программе программисту (ещё более специфично для приложения). Использование абстрактных общих неспецифичных для конкретной программы сообщений таких как в [`sysexits.h`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=misc/sysexits.h;h=37246b6e752fad0122d842bd479b59d127975bb8;hb=HEAD)  не помогает ни первому ни второму случаю. Чтобы увидеть варианты сообщений, можно посмотреть на базу правил для ошибок у [замечательной утилиты `thefuck`](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck), которая пытается автоматически поправить возникшие ошибки в командной строке.

> **В:** Кто-нибудь знает функцию, подобную strerror или strsignal только для exit status кодов?

Стандартной такой функции нет и не должно быть. Отдельные программы могут реализовывать подобные функции, например, в самом вопросе  ссылка на `sm_strexit()`. Чем более специфичны сообщения для программы тем лучше.

Например, представим какой-то программе для работы нужен файл, а он не существует и программа вынуждена завершится. Если программа напишет безличное и общее сообщение: *«input/output error»*, то это почти бесполезно. Полезное сообщение должно как минимум упомянуть имя файла: *«%s file not found»* (поддержка шаблонов нужна). А человеческое сообщение по-хорошему упомянет что случилось и как решить проблему на языке пользователя, упоминая низкоуровневые детали такие как IOError только если необходимо, например, если пользователь Питон-программист, то вот полезное сообщение об ошибке:

*«Словарь произношений не найден. Причина: X файл не существует. Чтобы загрузить, выполните `import nltk; nltk.download("cmudict")`»*

что является более адекватным  чем  абстрактное *«input/output error»*. Разница между ними—это основная причина почему exceptions используются для обработок ошибок во многих языках: информация, доступная в месте где произошла ошибка (например, системный вызов вернул `errno.ENOENT`: no such file or directory), отличается от информации выше по стеку где эту ошибку можно исправить. Сообщение об ошибке при выходе из программы находится на самом верху и должно использовать язык понятный человеку, ответственному за решение проблемы (например, пользователь программы). В выбранном примере можно обсудить, почему программа автоматически не выполнила необходимые действия (не зря `thefuck` существует), но в любом случае действия крайне вероятно будут уникальны для программы и поэтому наличие функции с абстрактным сообщением подталкивало бы программиста к выводу менее полезного сообщения.

Если рассматривать утилиты, принадлежащие только определённому семейству, то возможно имеет смысл синхронизировать некоторые сообщения об ошибках, чтобы одинаковые проблемы, которые могут быть разрешены  одинаково в рамках семейства, были бы одинаково решены (излишнее разнообразие не нужно).

**Кратко:** не следует поощрять сообщения типа «input/output error» в качестве сообщений об ошибке при выходе из программы и поэтому им не место в "базе знаний".

> **В:** ...На самом деле я ловил (год уже прошел) в wait чужие коды возврата от заранее не известно каких команд и выводил текстовое сообщение. Вот и хотел посмотреть, что (помимо найденного мной) пишут люди (совершенно не обязательно, что я этим реально воспользуюсь :-)). IMHO приятней видеть что-то более осмысленное, нежели abc exited with code NNN. Понятно (к сожалению, не мой случай), что если есть возможность вытащить из stderr (или лога) оригинальное сообщение, то надо это делать

Если задача, найти примеры сообщений, которые реальные программы перед выходом печатают, то либо запускать эти программы с разными параметрами и перехватывать вывод, либо смотреть в исходники (если достаточно только значение exit status без точного сообщения, то может быть достаточно  документацию для соответствующей команды посмотреть).

Обычно программы используют аналог функции, которая форматирует сообщение об ошибке и (опционально) выходит с заданным кодом, например, [`error()` функция из coreutils/gnulib](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob;f=lib/error.h;h=6a69db093585c99112b68d91f9e33c94ad22a1e0;hb=HEAD). Простой `grep 'error ('` возвращает сотни сообщений. Кстати, в подавляющем большинстве случаев единственный код выхода используется: `EXIT_FAILURE` (с разными сообщениями естественно).

Вот результат grep для [coreutils' checkout](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html)—выборка сообщений, которые перед выходом печатаются утилитами типа `cp`, `date`, `wc`, `dd`, `chown`, etc:

```
$ grep -A2 '\<error ([^0]' *.c | grep -oP '\("\K[^"]*(?="\))' | sort -u
-
/
.
2
block special files not supported
both files cannot be standard input
cannot change root directory to %s
cannot chdir to root directory
cannot combine any two of {ascii,ebcdic,ibm}
cannot combine block and unblock
cannot combine direct and nocache
cannot combine excl and nocreat
cannot combine lcase and ucase
cannot create link %s to %s
cannot create temporary file in %s
cannot determine hostname
cannot do --relative without --symbolic
cannot find name for user ID %lu
cannot follow %s by name
cannot fstat %s
cannot get effective GID
cannot get effective UID
cannot get niceness
cannot get real GID
cannot get real UID
cannot get system name
cannot get the size of %s
cannot open directory %s
cannot open %s for reading
cannot print only names or real IDs in default format
cannot print security context when user specified
cannot read file names from %s
cannot read realtime clock
cannot read table of mounted file systems
cannot run %s
cannot set hostname; this system lacks the functionality
cannot set name to %s
cannot set niceness
cannot set permissions of %s
cannot set %s
cannot set target context and preserve it
cannot skip past end of combined input
cannot specify both --data and --file-system
cannot specify both printing across and printing in parallel
cannot specify number of columns when printing in parallel
cannot stat %s
cannot unlink %s
cannot unset %s
can't get process context
character special files not supported
closing input file %s
closing input pipe
closing output file %s
closing output pipe
closing prior pipe
closing standard input
conflicting empty-field replacement strings
--context (-Z) works only on an SELinux-enabled kernel
couldn't create process for %s -d
couldn't find directory entry in %s with matching i-node
couldn't get boot time
--data needs at least one argument
delimiter list ends with an unescaped backslash: %s
division by zero
empty record separator
empty tab
error canonicalizing %s
error in regular expression matcher
error in regular expression search
error monitoring inotify event
error reading inotify event
error reading %s
error writing %s
extra operand %s not allowed with -%c
failed to access %s
failed to chdir to %s
failed to close input pipe
failed to compute a new context
failed to create pipe
failed to create security context: %s
failed to find %s
failed to get attributes of %s
failed to get current context
failed to get security context of %s
failed to get supplemental groups
failed to open %s
failed to prepare value '%Lf' for printing
failed to redirect standard error
failed to render standard input unusable
failed to restore the default file creation context
failed to return to initial working directory
failed to set default file creation context to %s
failed to set FILE environment variable
failed to set group-ID
failed to set new range: %s
failed to set new role: %s
failed to set new type: %s
failed to set new user: %s
failed to set supplemental groups
failed to set the copy of stderr to close on exec
failed to set user-ID
failed to stat %s
failed to update the environment with %s
file %d is not in sorted order
fork system call failed
format %s ends in %%
format %s has no %% directive
format %s has too many %% directives
format %s has unknown %%%c directive
--grouping cannot be combined with --format
grouping cannot be combined with --to
grouping has no effect in this locale
incompatible join fields %lu, %lu
incompatible tabs
input disappeared
input line is too long
invalid adjustment %s
invalid context: %s
invalid conversion specifier in suffix: \\%.3o
invalid conversion specifier in suffix: %c
invalid date format %s
invalid date %s
invalid device %s %s
invalid field number: %s
invalid field specifier: %s
invalid field width: %s
invalid file number in field spec: %s
invalid flags in conversion specification: %%%c%c
invalid format %s (width overflow)
invalid gap width: %s
invalid group %s
invalid group: %s
invalid header value %s
invalid input
invalid input range
invalid line count: %s
invalid line width
invalid line width: %s
invalid major device number %s
invalid minor device number %s
invalid mode
invalid mode %s
invalid number
invalid number of bytes
invalid number of chunks
invalid number of seconds: %s
invalid padding value %s
invalid page range %s
invalid precision in format %s
invalid precision: %s
invalid suffix in input %s: %s
invalid suffix %s, contains directory separator
invalid template, %s, contains directory separator
invalid --threshold argument '-0'
invalid time style format %s
invalid unit size: %s
invalid universal character name \\%c%0*x
invalid user %s
line count option -%s%c... is too large
line number overflow
line number %s is smaller than preceding line number, %s
maximum --%s argument with current rlimit is %s
minimum --%s argument is %s
misaligned [:upper:] and/or [:lower:] construct
missing %% conversion specification in suffix
missing conversion specifier in suffix
missing hexadecimal number in escape
mode must specify only file permission bits
moving input pipe
multi-character separator %s
multi-character tab %s
multiple compress programs specified
multiple field specifications
multiple -i options specified
multiple levelranges
multiple output delimiters specified
multiple output files specified
multiple output formats specified
multiple random sources specified
multiple roles
multiple separator characters specified
multiple target directories specified
multiple types
multiple users
no file systems processed
no group specified for unknown uid: %d
no input from %s
no lines to repeat
no login name
non-integer argument
no SHELL environment variable, and no shell type option given
no type may be specified when dumping strings
number in parallel must be nonzero
only one [c*] repeat construct may appear in string2
only one device may be specified
options '-%s' are incompatible
option used in invalid context -- %c
option --zero not permitted in default format
output file suffixes exhausted
page number overflow
'--pages=FIRST_PAGE[:LAST_PAGE]' missing argument
page width too narrow
-R --dereference requires either -H or -L
read error
reading directory %s
record too large
-R -h requires -P
%s: cannot change nonblocking mode
%s: cannot determine file size
%s: closing delimiter '%c' missing
%s: couldn't reset non-blocking mode
%s [-d] terminated abnormally
separator cannot be empty
%s: error setting %s
%s: error truncating
setting flags for %s
%s: file too long
%s (for regexp %s)
%s: input contains an odd number of tokens
%s: integer expected after delimiter
%s}: integer required between '{' and '}'
%.*s: invalid conversion specification
%s: invalid count at start of %s
%s: invalid directive
%s: invalid field specification %s
%s: invalid pattern
%s: '}' is required in repeat count
%s is too large
skip-bytes + read-bytes is too large
%s: line number must be greater than zero
%s:%lu: invalid zero-length file name
%s may be used only on a SELinux kernel
%s: no size information for this device
%s: no such user
%s: number of bytes is too large
squfof queue overflow
standard input
standard input is closed
standard output
%s: too many checksum lines
%s: unable to perform all requested operations
%s would overwrite input; aborting
syntax error
tabs are too far apart
tab size cannot be 0
tab sizes must be ascending
tab stop value is too large
target directory not allowed when installing a directory
target %s is not a directory
the [c*] repeat construct may not appear in string1
the delimiter must be a single character
the strings compared were %s and %s
the strip option may not be used when installing a directory
the untransformed string was %s
too few X's in template %s
too many characters in set
too many %% conversion specifications in suffix
too many input lines
too many repeated lines
unable to set security context %s
unknown program %s
unknown status from command (0x%X)
waiting for child process
waiting for %s [-d]
when not truncating set1, string2 must be non-empty
when specifying an output style, modes may not be set
with FILE=%s, exit %d from command: %s
with FILE=%s, signal %s from command: %s
with --suffix, template %s must end in X
write error
```

Comment: Замечательно подробный обзор, очевидно полезный потребителям *базы знаний*. Насколько я понимаю, у Вас также не текстов, отличных от тех, что размещены в вопросе?

Comment: @avp обновил ответ

Comment: jfs, спасибо. Все очень подробно и полезно для написания своей  программы, которая  пишет сообщение перед exit. На самом деле я ловил (год уже прошел)  в wait чужие коды возврата от заранее не известно каких команд  и выводил текстовое сообщение. Вот и хотел посмотреть, что (помимо найденного мной) пишут люди (совершенно не обязательно, что я этим реально воспользуюсь :-)). IMHO  приятней видеть что-то более  осмысленное, нежели `abc exited with code NNN`. Понятно (к сожалению, не мой случай), что если есть возможность вытащить из stderr (или лога) оригинальное сообщение, то надо это делать.

Answer (score 2):

ответы из комментариев:

---

все эти коды - программнозависимы. То есть, разработчики каждой программы выбирают их на свое усмотрение. Узнать расшифровки обычно можно в исходниках и манах (секция DIAGNOSTICS или RETURN VALUES).

> если программа вернула код из sysexits.h, то какое сообщение записать в лог?

если программа абстрактная, то возвращайте число, главное его обрамить правильно (типа "Error code: XXXX"), чтобы потом было легко искать по логу. А потом числа можно и декодировать по листингу:) плюсы - числа занимают меньше места - их легче обрабатывать - исключается возможность, что на два разных числа будет один текст.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю свой же вопрос, интересны *конкретные варианты* ***текста*** *сообщений*, а не общие рассуждения на заданную тему.

Comment: @avp, насколько я понимаю написанное, из утверждения «все эти коды — программнозависимы» прямо следует, что *конекретных вариантов **текста** сообщений* в природе не существует: у каждой программы/библиотеки свои собственные ошибки и свои собственные тексты.

Comment: мне казалось очевидным, что говоря совсем простыми словами, вопрос сводится к --  *я хочу увидеть варианты таких сообщений*. Но, если посмотреть на  дату   вопроса , видимо не судьба (да и практически это уже не актуально).