# Почему две ошибки FileNotFoundError и selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException при запуске firefox?

Tags: python, selenium

Пытаюсь запустить скрипт чтобы отрыть firefox

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python C:\1\test1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\1\test1.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 148, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Понял, что не хватает geckodriver , что еще не так?

Comment: Добавьте папку, где лежит geckodriver в PATH, перезапустите то, через что запускаете тест и проверьте еще раз. После этого будем решать не хватает чего-то еще или нет

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка у вас только одна: `'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.` (не найдена `geckodriver` программа).

Вы видите две ошибки, потому что более высокоуровневая ошибка `WebDriverException` обнаружена на уровне системы как `FileNotFoundError`  при попытке запуска `geckodriver` команды. Питон 3 показывает всю цепочку исключений, если явно не подавить.

То есть авторы selenium решили обернуть более общую низкоуровневую ошибку: `[WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл` более специфичной высокоуровневой `'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.` для удобства, чтобы явно указать как исправить ошибку: добавить geckodriver в `%PATH%`.

Связанный вопрос [Функция, возвращающая текст для exit status codes, defined in sysexits.h](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521614/23044).

Comment: здравствуйте, не знаете как решить данную проблему? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1080752/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83